# Mouse Hover not working in Selenum C#

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver, mouseover

I want hover over a label which reveal the text hidden under it.

Before Hover: [image]

After Hover: [image]

See here and you will get a clear idea http://screencast.com/t/VO6rYzLNAvEy.

Mouse Hover is working fine in Chrome version: 41.0.2272.101

But not working in Firefox version: 36.0.4

What I have tried:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(_driver);
IAction a=builder.MoveToElement(_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='CardholderGrid']//tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span"))).Build();
     a.Perform();
```

No issues with XPath.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just did. Still getting Same issues.

Comment: Any error are you getting?

Comment: No Errors.
making point clear again: Mouse over working fine in chrome. **Issue is seen only in fire fox**